# Print PDF as image from command line?

Tags: pdf, command-line, printing, acrobat

Is it possible to print a PDF as image using Acrobat Reader through command line options?

Or this feature is only available through the GUI of Acrobat?

Comment: You can use also GIMP. It's very fast. It will import pages as layer of the same image and export as PDF with pages of every layer. All pages will be just images, no more editable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately for you, the answer is *"No!"*. Printing PDF pages as an image is only available through the GUI in Acrobat Reader.

To see a list with all available options, run this:

```
acroread -help
```

To see an explanation for all the available options, run this:

```
man acroread
```

(I assume you are using `acroread` on Linux or Unix. Because on Windows, you'd have even less CLI options for it... and some incomplete documentation of which is [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters_v9.pdf).)

Answer (score 4):

Note that Ghostscript can convert PDF's to image and you can use this from command line (useful for scripting).

For instance, on unix to convert a PDF to JPEG pages at 90 dpi, use:

```
gs -r90 -sDEVICE=jpeg -o out-%d.jpg in.pdf
```

will create individual pages as out-1.jpg, out-2.jpg, etc.

Comment: Goulutor probably wants to use the "Print as Image" feature of Acroread for sending the job to the printer, while using other Acro(Read) print features (such as print a pamphlet, or scale, or n-up). "Print as Image" often is useful if you otherwise encounter font rendering problems in the printout...

Comment: Exactly. We encounter problems in the printout and "print as image" might solve the problem.