# How to print a PDF file from command line or by npm library?

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, pdf, command-line

I need to print a PDF file and i have two choices:

> - printing from nodejs app
> - executing from command line.

From node i have tried "printer", "node-native-printer, "node-printer" libraries but when i try to print my PDF i get a lot of pages with the file's source code printed in every page.
From command line i tried lp/lpr and and also in this case I get the same result, lot of pages with source code (as if i were opening the PDF with a text editor and print what you can see there).
I also tried to make a .txt file like this:

```
AAAAAAAAAAAA
qwerty
zxcvbnm
```

but lp/lpr prints only the first line of `AAAAAAAAAAAA`

I have also tried in windows, from command line (PDFtoPrinter command) prints the PDF correctly.

Actual printer in use: " Xerox WorkCentre 3225", with drivers installed both on windows and linux.

**EDIT 1**

My .pdf file is not just a text file, it contains text, barcodes etc. so i can't convert to txt.

**EDIT 2**

I found a solution:

> - pdf2ps filename.pdf filename.ps
> - lpr filename.ps

This works, but i would like to know if there is a solution to print it directly.

Comment: Could you provide the command lines you've tried for using `lp`/`lpr` ?

Comment: "lp filename.pdf", "lpr filename.pdf", "lpr -o PDF filename.pdf".
Tried to convert pdf into jpg and "lpr filename.jpg" gave similar result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print PDF from command line in Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/421341), [CUPS printing of PDF files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8562292/608639), [Print PDF as image from command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6504036/608639), [Printing PDFs from Windows Command Line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19124808/608639), etc. (This looks like a [Super User](http://superuser.com/) question to me).

Answer (score 1):

If you have or can install `enscript`,  you can try:

```
enscript file.txt -o - | ps2pdf - text.pdf | lp -d <PRINTERNAME>
```

You may need `ghostscript` installed as well because I think `ps2pdf` is part of `ghostscript`.

I am only putting the conversion to PDF part because you give an example with text file and also mention a page printed with codes, so maybe there is a conversion step between txt and pdf which outputs something malformed.

In order to know the printer name, you can run `lpstat -p -d`. It will show you the list of available printers.

EDIT:

Alright I saw your edit, in this case you still can write a shell function to do all this in one go. It does not exactly answer your question, but it is equally seemless.

In your `.bashrc` or equivalent:

```
function pdfprint() {
  pdf2ps "$1" | lpr
}
```

And use it that way:

```
pdfprint filename.pdf
```

Comment: You are right i was not so clear. I edited the qestion, is not just a simple text file, i tried to convert to txt but it will be not correct.